# Unwanted text added with copy/paste from Notepad++ to Shell

Tags: shell, text, editor

When I copy text, from my text editor, Notepad++, to the Linux command line, unwanted text is inserted.  I have invisible characters shown in Notepad++ and UTF-8 encoding.  Here is an example of text I copy from the text editor:

if [ ! -e "${SAMPL}" ] ; then
echo "Still a problem with $SAMPL!"
fi

When I paste at the command line, it appears with an unwanted line of text:
$ if [ ! -e "${SAMPL}" ] ; then

> echo "Still a problem with $SAMPL!"
>   echo "Still a problem with $SAMPL"${DATAPATH}${SAMPL}"
>   fi

Is there something obvious I can fix?
Thank you!

Comment: I would first verify that the effect you see, really comes from copying the text. First, I would paste the text into a different text editor and see, whether things look normal. Then, I would produce a dump of the pasted text in the command line window. For doing this, I would use the command `od -cx >dump.txt`, paste the text, type control-d to end the *od*-command, and then look at dump.txt. Does it contain unwanted character? In particular, does it contain a carriage-return (*0d*, respectively *\r*)?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply!  Unfortunately, my interactive session was canceled so I cannot recreate this error.  I did check with a different text editor and there was no added text in this editor.  I think the problem has something to do with the shell somehow reinterpreting blank spaces and filling them in with some variable I unintentionally set.  In the future I will use the od command to examine the text.  Is there something I should look for in the od output?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes - look for everything which isn't supposed to be there. It is *your* file, so you know what is supposed to be in and what not. In particular, pay attention to every byte outside the printable ASCII range (although, since you are doing UTF-8, some of these might legally occur in, say, comments or strings). Also, make sure that the file is saved without BOM. I was often bitten by this .....